# How to customise push notification sound in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am making a chat app. The user can select the notification sound for a particular chat/group. When the app is in the killed state, if a new message arrives I want to play the sound that the user had selected for that chat otherwise play default sound. How can I do this?

Comment: Will it be better to send the the selected sound by the user to the server where it will be saved for future notifications or change the sound payload every time the notification arrives from the server for that user by maintaining some local db?

Answer (score 0):

1. App bundle must have your all sounds file
2. User selected sound name and feedback to you app server
3. Your APN server get the selected sound and push notification with the sound name

Comment: In whatsapp/telegram when I select notification sound for a particular chat, do these apps send these sound names to the server for future use in push notification or do they modify the payload after it arrives?

Comment: @ShubhamMishra  App send sound id to server when user selected. Server send notification which payload contain the sound name.